# HTML-теги работают неправильно

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Значение переменной не записывается в `value` , но в поле для заполнения появляется ошибка:

> Notice:  Undefined variable: name in D:\xampp\htdocs\trening\index.php on line 20

Вот так написано, не могу понять что такое:

```
<?php
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mdb','root','');
  $db->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
  if(count($_POST)>0){
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $text = trim($_POST['text']);
      if($name!=''&&$text!=''){
        $query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO coments SET name='$name' text='$text'");
        $query->execute();
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
      }
  }
  $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coments ORDER BY dt DESC");
  $query->execute();
  $arr=$query->fetchAll();
?>
<form method="post";>
  Имя<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"><br>
  Коментарий<br>
  <textarea name="text"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

---

Comment: Добавьте код хотя бы.

Comment: Переменной такой нет. Или написана неправильно. Вот и выводит undefined (с англ. неизвестная).

Comment: Покажите,  что вы записываете в $name

Comment: @КириллЖелнов показал

Comment: А в бд запись добавляется?

Comment: Тут вопрос на миллион, но возможно $_POST приходит пустым.

Comment: var_dump($name) сотворит чудеса. Откуда в value появится $name, если он образуется после сабмита формы? <form> прописан без action, то есть при сабмите текущая страница перезагружается, возвращая все элементы формы к их значениям по умолчанию.

Comment: @labris спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Условие if(count($_POST)>0) не выполняется, поэтому переменная считается не объявленной.
Можно сделать значение по умолчанию в else:

```
 if(count($_POST)>0){
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$text = trim($_POST['text']);
  if($name!=''&&$text!=''){
    $query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO coments SET name='$name' text='$text'");
    $query->execute();
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
  }
} else {
 $name = 'значение по умолчанию';
}
```